# In the paint application, the drawing is saving as image but not sharing to the other apps

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, bitmap, file-sharing

When I am clicking on the saving button, the drawing is saving in the image format but it is not sharing. Whenever sharing options shown for sharing, clicking on any app resulting displaying a toast, with the message "Sharing failed, please try again."
Only sharing feature is not working, else the app is working fine.

**Manifest file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.nandini.android.drawdoodle">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DrawDoodle">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:authorities="com.nandini.android.fileprovider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/path"/>
        </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**path.xml file in xml directory**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path
        name="Captured"
        path="Android/data/com.nandini.android.drawdoodle/files"/>
</paths>
```

**MainActivity.kt file**

```
package com.nandini.android.drawdoodle

import android.Manifest
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import androidx.core.view.get
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var drawingView:DrawingClass?=null
    private var brush_btn:ImageButton?=null
    private var mCurrentPaintBtn:ImageButton?=null
    private var picture_btn : ImageButton?=null
    private var undo_btn:ImageButton?=null
    private var save_btn:ImageButton?=null
    private var customProgressDialog:Dialog?=null

    val openGalleryLauncher:ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
        result->
        if(result.resultCode== RESULT_OK && result.data!=null){
            var imageBackground:ImageView=findViewById(R.id.iv_background)
            imageBackground.setImageURI(result.data?.data)
        }
    }

    val requestPermission: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>> = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions())
    {
        permissions->
        permissions.entries.forEach{
               val permissionName=it.key
               val isGranted=it.value

            if(isGranted){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                val pickIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                openGalleryLauncher.launch(pickIntent)
            }
            else{
                if(permissionName== Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }}
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        drawingView=findViewById(R.id.drawingId)
        picture_btn=findViewById(R.id.picture_btn)
        undo_btn=findViewById(R.id.undo_btn)
        save_btn=findViewById(R.id.save_btn)

        val colour_linear_layout=findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.colour_linear_layout)
        mCurrentPaintBtn=colour_linear_layout[1] as ImageButton
        mCurrentPaintBtn!!.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.pallete_selected))
        brush_btn=findViewById(R.id.brush_btn)
        brush_btn?.setOnClickListener{
            showBrushSizeDialog()
        }
        picture_btn?.setOnClickListener{
            requestStoragePermission()
        }
        undo_btn?.setOnClickListener{
            drawingView?.onUndo()
        }
        save_btn?.setOnClickListener{
            if(isStorageAllowed()){
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    val flDrawingView:FrameLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawing_frame_layout)
                    saveBitmapFile(getBitmapFromView(flDrawingView))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun showBrushSizeDialog(){
        val BrushSizeDialog=Dialog(this)
        BrushSizeDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_brush_size)
        BrushSizeDialog.setTitle("Brush Size")
        val smallBtn:ImageButton=BrushSizeDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush)
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener{
            drawingView?.setSizeForBrush(10.toFloat())
            BrushSizeDialog.dismiss()
        }
        val mediumBtn:ImageButton=BrushSizeDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush)
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener{
            drawingView?.setSizeForBrush(20.toFloat())
            BrushSizeDialog.dismiss()
        }
        val LargeBtn:ImageButton=BrushSizeDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush)
        LargeBtn.setOnClickListener{
            drawingView?.setSizeForBrush(30.toFloat())
            BrushSizeDialog.dismiss()
        }
        BrushSizeDialog.show()
    }

fun paintClicked(view: View){
    if(view!==mCurrentPaintBtn){
        val imageButton=view as ImageButton
        val colorTag=imageButton.tag.toString()
        drawingView?.setColor(colorTag)
        imageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.pallete_selected))
        mCurrentPaintBtn?.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.pallete))
        mCurrentPaintBtn=view
    }
}

    fun isStorageAllowed():Boolean{
        showProgressDialog()
        val result=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        return result==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    fun requestStoragePermission(){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            showRationaleDialog("Draw Doodle","Draw Doodle requires access to External Storage.")
        }else{
            requestPermission.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        }
    }
    
    fun showRationaleDialog(
        title : String,
        message: String
    ){
        val builder:AlertDialog.Builder=AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("Cancel"){dialog,_->dialog.dismiss()}
        builder.create().show()
    }

private fun getBitmapFromView(view:View): Bitmap? {
    val returnedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width,view.height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas=Canvas(returnedBitmap)
    val bgDrawable=view.background
    if(bgDrawable !=null){
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas)
    }else{
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    }
    view.draw(canvas)
    return returnedBitmap
}
    private suspend fun saveBitmapFile(mBitmap: Bitmap?):String{
        var result =""
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            if(mBitmap !=null){
                try {
                    val bytes=ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,bytes)

                    val f = File(externalCacheDir?.absoluteFile?.toString()+ File.separator+"Draw_Doodle"+System.currentTimeMillis()/1000+".png")

                    val fo=FileOutputStream(f)
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
                    fo.close()

                    result=f.absolutePath

                    runOnUiThread{
                        cancelProgressDialog()
                        if(result.isNotEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"File saved successfully : $result",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            shareImage(result)
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Something went wrong.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (e:Exception){
                    result=""
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }

private fun showProgressDialog(){
    customProgressDialog=Dialog(this@MainActivity)
    customProgressDialog?.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom_progress)
    customProgressDialog?.show()
}

    private fun cancelProgressDialog(){
        if(customProgressDialog !=null){
            customProgressDialog?.dismiss()
            customProgressDialog=null
        }
    }

    private fun shareImage(result:String){
         MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, arrayOf(result),null){
             path,uri->
             val shareIntent=Intent()
             shareIntent.action=Intent.ACTION_SEND
             shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri)
             shareIntent.type="image/png"
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share"))
         }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawing_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawing_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/colour_linear_layout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <com.nandini.android.drawdoodle.DrawingClass
            android:id="@+id/drawingId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#80ffffff"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_btns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/colour_linear_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/undo_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/img4" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/brush_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/p1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/picture_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/img3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/save_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/img5" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/colour_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/drawing_frame_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/action_btns">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:tag="@color/yellow"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/pink"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="@color/pink"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="@color/green"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="@color/red"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="@color/blue"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/skin"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="@color/skin"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="@color/orange"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/purple"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="@color/purple"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/dark_cyan"
            android:tag="@color/dark_cyan"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:tag="@color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/pallete" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `shareIntent.setData(uri)`? I'd suggest using this though `shareIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/png")`.

Comment: It is still not working!